# Is there a best practice for designing the MVVM schema graphically?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am learning MVVM. At this point I have this type of data flow:

```
from:
View - AView.xaml
DataContext - AViewModel.cs
Schema: View first

calls to: 
View - BView.xaml
DataContext - BViewModel.cs
Schema: View first
```

BView.xaml contains a ScrollViewer that usea ContentControl to display the CView.xaml.

```
Inside ScrollViewer:
from:
    View - CView.xaml
    DataContext - CViewModel.cs
    Schema: ViewModel first

calls to:
    View - DView
    DataContext - DViewModel.cs
    Schema: ViewModel first
```

Additionally, the ViewModel's displayed are children from one or another BaseViewModel and may implement one or more interfaces.

Is there a recommended, standard, or best way of outlining this textually or graphically? There must be a good way of outlining this.

Thanks for any ideas or suggestions.

Comment: Need a little help here trying to understand your question. What is the nature of the 'data flow' from A to B, and B to C, etc. I'm very unclear about your terminology.

Comment: @Dean Hi. Not having a standard, this is my shorthand. The "from" is what is being displayed before a menu item or selection is made. "To" is better as "Calls to". The "Schema" is my way of knowing if the View sets its datacontext (as in View first) or an ItemsControl is pairing the data, viewmodel, with a view (as in ViewModel first). I was hoping for a standard that on one-page a year from now, I could glance at it and know where to look for modifications in the design.